# Postgres: select data from table based on few clauses on relationship table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have two tables:

```
person (
    id int,
    name varchar,
    surname varchar
)

vehicle (
    id int,
    make varchar,
    model varchar,
    has_gps boolean,
    has_ac boolean
    person_id
)
```

I want to select all persons who have at least one vehicle that has GPS (has_gps = true) and at least one vehicle that has AC (has_ac = true).

So basically person must have minimum of 2 vehicles, but there must be at least one vehicle that has GPS and at least one vehicle that has AC.

I tried with exists, but I can't seem to figure out how I could do this in postgres.

For example:

```
Person (1, 'Michael', 'Jordan')
Person (2, 'Leo', 'Messi')

Vehicle (1, 'bmw', 'x5', true, false, 1)
Vehicle (2, 'ferrari', 'testarossa', false, true, 1)
Vehicle (3, 'mercedes', 's class', true, true, 2)
```

In the results I should only get Person with ID 1, because it has at least one vehicle with gps and at least one with ac.

Comment: Why can't it be the same vehicle?

Comment: It can, but I'm interested in this case. Person and vehicle are just tables for example, maybe it's not the best example, but I think you can get the point.

Comment: Sample data, expected result?

Comment: It's edited. I added example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :

```
select person_id from vehicle
group by person_id
having
count(case when has_gps then 1 end ) > 0
and
count(case when has_ac then 1 end ) > 0
and
count(*) > 1
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` give the expected result:

```
SELECT person_id
FROM vehicle
WHERE has_gps = true OR has_ac = true 
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d1eaf4c12fabc4eb333e2881ece9104a)